# Maximum File Count Per Folder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

Is there a way to set a maximum number of files that can exist in a given folder? For example, if I had a folder for sales reports, I might want to set the maximum number of reports to ten, i.e., I don't want the sales folder to have more than ten files. I am using SSRS 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are referring to folders on the Report Server. There's no option to limit the number of files in a folder. There's no practical way to implement this functionality without a very elaborate workaround. Especially if you care about the user experience when you try to add that 11th file.